# php string in to array (key and val must be same string)

Tags: php, arrays

Using explode i have converted the string into array  ,

But the array look like 
Array ( [0] => root)

But i want i make my array somthing like Array ( [root] => root)

How to make this manner..

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$array = explode($separator, $some_string);
$array = array_combine($array, $array);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could make it an associative array like so:

```
$exploded = explode (.......);
$exploded_associative = array();

foreach ($exploded as $part) 
 if ($part) 
  $exploded_associative[$part] = $part;

print_r($exploded_associative); // Will output "root" => "root" ....
```

what exactly do you need this for?